# opencv-java UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java2411 in java.library.path on mac

Tags: c++, macos, opencv

I'm having a problem in implementing the tutorial:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html
in the last step.

I always get the following error message:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java2411 in java.library.path
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java2411 in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
at HelloOpenCV.main(HelloOpenCV.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)**
```

I have searching for many information on Internet, many people said that I should change java.library.path in this condition. 
So I change my code from

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

to

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", "/Users/dasing/Downloads/opencv-2.4.11/build/lib");<br>
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);**
```

where in **/Users/dasing/Downloads/opencv-2.4.11/build/lib** contains a file whose name is *libopencv_java2411.dylib* (I looked from the site http://answers.opencv.org/question/7958/no-opencv_java244-in-javalibrarypath/ )

but it is still not work!

My question is the error message is that "no **opencv_java2411** in java.library.path", but in the folder lib, the file name is "libopencv_java2411.dylib". I don't think it is the same... there are only one file named "opencv_java2411", but its type is "jar".....

Please help me! Thank you very much!!